# How to simplify $1-\frac1{a+b+1} $

Tags: calculus, functions

I have this term with two factors a and b. a and b are positive integer numbers.

$$1-\frac1{a+b+1}$$

b is an error in the problem that I want to separate it from the problem.
For example such that $x$ shouldn't depend on $a$.

$1-\frac1{a+b+1}=1-\frac1{a+1}+x$

any idea?
How to represent the error?

Comment: This is not possible, because the result would be $$x = \frac{1}{a+b+1}-\frac{1}{a+1} = -\frac{1}{(a+b+1)(a+1)},$$ and this generally depends on $a$. But maybe I misunderstood your question.

Comment: @gammatester Shouldn't there be $b$ instead of $1$ in the numerator?

Comment: @savick01 b is an error that may be with a. I don't know how to represent it and how to separate it from a.

Comment: @savick01: Yes of course you are right with $b$ in the numerator, but I cannot edit the comment.

Comment: You can't separate it from $a$ that way. If $a$ is about $-1$ then denominator of your expression $\frac{1}{a+b+1}$ is almost $0$ so even a small error ($b$) may change a lot. I think that relative error is more appropriate than the absolute error. Maybe you should present the original problem here?

Comment: By relative error I mean considering $\frac{\frac{1}{a+b+1}}{\frac{1}{a+1}}$ instead of $\frac{1}{a+b+1} - \frac{1}{a+1}$. It will anyway depend on $a$ but it will be easy to bound it in terms of $b$.

Comment: @savick01 the real factor is 1-(1/(a+b+1)) and b is an error.the real value must be 1-(1/(a+1)) without b that i want to separate it from my problem.

Comment: You just edited your question to change the meaning.  Surely you don't mean that $x$ shouldn't depend on $b$?

Comment: Oh, sorry, I forgot about $1$. It still makes sense to consider relative error but it is not much simpler than the absolute error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are asking for is impossible (as has already been pointed out in a comment).  If we write
$$
1 - \frac{1}{a+b+1} = 1 - \frac{1}{1+a} + x~,
$$
then $x$ necessarily depends on both $a$ and $b$ (just solve the above equation for it).

Perhaps the following will suffice for your purposes: if $b$ is much smaller than $1+a$, then we can get a good approximation by taking the first-order Taylor expansion around $b=0$:
$$
1 - \frac{1}{a+b+1} \simeq 1 - \frac{1}{1+a} + \frac{b}{(1+a)^2}
$$
for $|b| \ll |a+1|$.
There is, however, no reasonable way to remove the dependence on $a$; the sensitivity of your formula to $b$ depends intrinsically on the value of $a$.

Comment: oh my God.So beautiful...you understand me very well. I forget Taylor expansion completely.Thanks.

Comment: @Fatime: You're welcome. :-)

Comment: Do you have any suggestion about [similar question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/462496/taylor-expansion-and-equation-simplification)?